# Trip Class Method Not Working Properly

Tags: c#, methods

I have to make a trip class that takes the user's input of destination, distance traveled, cost of gas, and numbers of gallons used and output the miles per gallon and cost per mile.

For some reason my mpg and cpm are always outputting 0, what am I doing wrong?

Program class:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Trip t1 = new Trip("Columbus, OH", 150, 2.95, 5);
        Trip t2 = new Trip("Edmonton, AB", 3300, 2.75, 50);
        Trip t3 = new Trip("Calgary, AB", 3100, 2.50, 45);

        Console.WriteLine(t1);
        Console.WriteLine(t2);
        Console.WriteLine(t3);
    }
}
```

Trip class

```
class Trip
{
    //class variables
    string destination;
    int distance;
    double costOfGas;
    int gallons;
    int mpg;
    double cpm;

    //constructors
    public Trip()
    {
        destination = "n.a.";
        distance = 1;
        costOfGas = 1;
        gallons = 1;
    }

    public Trip(string destinationValue, int distanceValue,
                double costOfGasValue, int gallonsValue)
    {
        Destination = destinationValue;
        Distance = distanceValue;
        CostOfGas = costOfGasValue;
        Gallons = gallonsValue;
    }

    //properties
    public string Destination
    {
        get { return destination; }
        set { destination = value; }
    }

    public int Distance
    {
        get { return distance; }
        set { distance = value; }
    }

    public double CostOfGas
    {
        get { return costOfGas; }
        set { costOfGas = value; }
    }

    public int Gallons
    {
        get { return gallons; }
        set { gallons = value; }
    }

    public int MPG
    {
        get { return mpg; }
        set { mpg = MilesPerGallon(value); }
    }

    public double CPM
    {
        get { return cpm; }
        set { cpm = CostPerMile(value); }
    }

    //user-defined methods
    public int MilesPerGallon(int value)
    {
        return distance / gallons;
    }

    public double CostPerMile(double value)
    {
        return costOfGas * mpg;
    }

    override
        public string ToString()
    {
        return "Trip["
            + destination + ", "
            + distance + ", "
            + costOfGas + ", "
            + gallons + "]"
            + "\n Miles Per Gallon = " + mpg
            + ", Cost Per Mile = " + cpm;
    }
}
```

Output:

Trip[Columbus, OH, 150, 2.95, 5]
 Miles Per Gallon = 0, Cost Per Mile = 0

etc.

Comment: It makes no sense for you class to allow setting the `MPG` and `CPM` properties.

Comment: because you never call CPM or CMP  propery in your code to so mpg and cmp filds never changed,they are always 0

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. Did you try to debug it?

Comment: You should be using auto properties for most of these, there's no need for backing fields.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KPeO5D This fiddle has the fixes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backing fields for `MPG` and `CPM` (`mpg` and `cpm`) are only set in the setters of those properties.  Since you never call the setters they never get set.

Instead you should calculate the values in the properties and not have setters at all

```
public int MPG
{
    get { return distance / gallons; }
}

public double CPM
{
    get { return costOfGas * MPG; }
}
```

and remove the backing fields and use the properties instead.

Comment: Yeah, just missed changing it to use the property instead.

Comment: Thank you. I did this before, but I used mpg, cpm instead of MPG and CPM so the result still remained the same. Simple mistake that I overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `mpg` and `cpm` and those values are never set. Your usages of `MPG` and `CPM` are weird too. You don't really need the `MPG` and `CPM` properties, update the `MilesPerGallon` and `CostPerMile` methods to be properties that just calculate the values:

```
public int MilesPerGallon { get { return distance / gallons; } }

public double CostPerMile { get { return costOfGas * MilesPerGallon; } }

override    
public string ToString()
{
    return "Trip["
        + destination + ", "
        + distance + ", "
        + costOfGas + ", "
        + gallons + "]"
        + "\n Miles Per Gallon = " + MilesPerGallon
        + ", Cost Per Mile = " + CostPerMile;
}
```

Comment: They make more sense as properties since the `value` argument is not used and not needed in those functions.

Comment: Maybe also get rid of the value args?